# Why is the following giving me zero?

Tags: swift, int, double, var

Every print statement below yields 0.0

```
var c:Double = 0.0
let a:Int = 1
let b:Int = 5
print("a/b = \(Double(a/b * 100))")
c = Double(a/b * 100)
print("c = \(c)")
```

Comment: Integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of integer division. Change `Double(a/b * 100)` to `Double(a) / Double(b) * 100`.

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Just saw that as soon as I submitted...I guess the iPad app isn’t as responsive as the browser :/